# Need to close additional FileHandler for JUL?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, java.util.logging

I'm using java util logging for logging in a small Java EE application. To add an additional FileHandler (for example for errors/warnings), I created a LoggerFactory that creates the actual logger and that statically add a filehandler to the "main" logger.

```
package de.il.myapp.logging;

public class LoggerFactory {

    private static final java.util.logging.Logger MAIN_LOGGER = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("de.il.myapp");

    static {
            try {
                final java.util.logging.FileHandler fh = new java.util.logging.FileHandler("error.log", 1024*1024, 5, true);
                fh.setLevel(Level.WARNING);

                final java.util.logging.Formatter formatterTxt = new java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter();
                fh.setFormatter(formatterTxt);
                MAIN_LOGGER.addHandler(fh);

            } catch (final IOException e) {
                //...
            }
        }
    }

    public static final Logger getLogger(final Class<?> clazz){
        return java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(clazz);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, except, when I stop the application, the lck file are still there. On a start, a new lck is created. So after some restarts the directory looks like this.

```
  error.log.0
  error.log.0.1
  error.log.0.1.lck
  error.log.0.2
  error.log.0.2.lck
  error.log.0.3
  error.log.0.3.lck
  error.log.0.lck
```

The question is: How can I avoid this? Do I have to close the filehandler at the end? But where? Since this is a Java EE application I don't you an exit point, do I? And why do I get ..log.0.X for the logfiles, not just ..log.0?

Thanks,
Ingo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Glassfish, you can use [Lifecycle Listeners](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beamc.html). In JBoss, you can use `StartupServiceMBean`. What app server are you using?

Comment: I'm using Websphere Application Server 7 (NOT community edition). You also know the name for this this app server? Should/ Can I handle it via a ServletContextListener?

Comment: Is this a Web app or a JEE app? In other words do you use your logger only inside Servlets, JSPs, etc. or are you also using it inside EJBs? If you are not using EJBs, yes, you can use `ServletContextListener`. Otherwise that wouldn't work.

Comment: Currently I only have MDBs and no Servlets, in other words a JEE app and I'm using the Logger in EJBs.

Comment: I haven't used WebSphere. But give my other answer a try.

Comment: Okay. I searched the WAS manual for something like Lifecycle Listeners. I came up with "Startup Service Beans". And I finally got to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not allowed to use `java.io` classes in EJBs:

Section 21.2.2 of the spec:

> An enterprise bean must not use the
>   java.io package to attempt to access
>   files and directo- ries in the file
>   system.

This means that you also should not use classes that in turn use `java.io` classes unless you obtain them by asking the container.

However if you create an eagerly loaded singleton session bean and perform the cleanup on `@PreDestroy`:

```
@Startup 
@Singleton 
public class FileHandlerCloser {

 @PreDestroy
 public void closeFileHandlers() {
  // close file handlers
 }

}
```

The spec is not very clear about this but I think singleton beans are destroyed after all other beans.